# Problem with export all animation to glb

Tags: animation, export

[image: it's just flat][image: This curve not show in the exported glb]I followed a shuffle card animation in this youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JnmWfWuMDw&t=3s. However, when I want to export the model into glb, some animation not showing up. I have researched many ways but still not working. I would really appreciate if anyone has any idea. Thank you so much!
P/s: I think there is a problem with apply modifier but I have ticked to apply modifier in the export but still not work. The card not show the curve at all. As in pic 1, the card support to be curve like the pic 2 but it's just flat.

Comment: Blender's modifiers will only work in Blender which is why there's an option to apply them before exporting. Unfortunately that will stop the animation exporting in this case because bending the cards depends on keyframes applied to Blender's Deform modifiers.

Comment: I've just known that by now. Been searching for solution for a while. Thank you very much for your clarification!